# Simple and convenient programs for blogging

Tags: 11.10, software-recommendation, blog

I want to write a blog just for myself. Is there any simple and convenient programs to do that? :)

Comment: Do you want to write a blog that is published on the World Wide Web but which requires authentication to access? Or would you prefer an application for keeping a locally stored journal?

Comment: If its an offline journal, you can see in the Software Center that `RedNotebook` has pretty good ratings, and looks pretty fine in the screenshot

Comment: @EliahKagan: just for myself. Thanks Wolter, I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to keep a local journal rather than a blog on the web with restricted access, you can use a program like [Lifeograph](http://lifeograph.wikidot.com/) or (as Wolter Hellmund suggested) [RedNotebook](http://rednotebook.sourceforge.net/), both of which can be installed in the Software Center.